# Setting ContentControl.Content back to null does not change UI

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, null, contentcontrol

I am developing an Windows Store App (8.1) using XAML. In the UI ContentControls with data-specific content are displayed. For this, I successfully use DataTemplateSelectors.

The following problem occurs: The initial ContentControl.Content property is null and the TemplateSelector returns my personal NullTemplate correctly. Afterwards, the content is set to the data object to display and the DataTemplateSelector successfully returns the correct template.

But if the Content property is set back to null, nothing happens. The DataTemplateSelector is not being called by the UI (even with both ***Core-methods overriden and implemented).

Here is the configuration of the ContentControl

```
                <ContentControl 
                    Content="{Binding ButtonContent,ElementName=root}"
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding ButtonContentTemplateSelector,ElementName=root}"/>
```

(Both Bindings provide the data correctly.)

The content template selector

```
public class DefaultComboBoxItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate NullTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ObjectTemplate { get; set; }

    public DefaultComboBoxItemTemplateSelector() : base() { }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null) return NullTemplate;
        else return ObjectTemplate;
    }
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        return SelectTemplateCore(item, null);
    }
}
```

Any ideas, why the UI does not use the NullTemplate after setting the Content property to null?

Cheers
Volker

Comment: On what condition does the 'ButtonContent' is changed? This should fire your template selector when there is an updated to this element.

Comment: Hi - actually I tried different settings. First, it was the underlying model, that changed. Upon visitting the associated page, the property of the data model will be set to null.

Comment: Secondly, once I found this issue, I introduced a button on that page, that explicitly sets the property to null upon CLICK.

Comment: Do you need more information on the code?